# Solution verification for problem dealing with complex eigenvalues and linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, solution-verification, linear-transformations

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a square matrix and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ be eigenvalue for $A$. Let $z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times 1}$ be the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$. Show that for the linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}, x\mapsto Ax$ the following holds $$f(E)=E$$ where $E=\operatorname{span}(x,y)$.

The proposed solution for this was the following. Denote the real part of $z$ by $\Re(z)=x$ and the imaginary part as $\Im(z)=y$. Now $$Ax=\Re(Az) = \Re(\lambda z) = \Re(\lambda)\Re(z) \color{red}{\textrm{$ -\Im(\lambda)\Im(z)$}} = \Re(\lambda)x -\Re(\lambda)y$$

Similarly $$Ay=\Im(Az)=\Im(\lambda z) =\color{red}{\textrm{$\Im(\lambda)\Re(z) + \Re(\lambda)\Im(z)$}} = \Im(\lambda)x+ \Im(\lambda)y$$

thus $f(x), f(y) \in E=\operatorname{span}(x,y)$. So $f(E) \subset E$.

Now let $v=v_1x+v_2y \in P$. If we can find $w=ax+by$ for which $\color{red}{\textrm{$Aw=v$}}$ then $E \subset f(E)$.

Now from above $Aw = \color{red}{\textrm{$(a\Re(\lambda) +b\Im(\lambda))x + (b\Re(\lambda) -a\Im(\lambda))y = v_1x+v_2y$}}$ and this can be represented as a system of equations which can then be represented by the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} \Re(\lambda) & \Im(\lambda) \\-\Im(\lambda) & \Re(\lambda) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a \\b \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\v_2\end{bmatrix}$$ which is invertible since $$\det\begin{bmatrix} \Re(\lambda) & \Im(\lambda) \\-\Im(\lambda) & \Re(\lambda) \end{bmatrix} = \lambda^2$$ and $\lambda \ne 0$. And thus there is a solution for the system. So $E \subset f(E) \implies f(E) = E$.

I cannot seem to understand where the parts marked red are coming from? Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you just write $\lambda =a+bi,$ with $a,b$ real, and write out the calculations, then this will be clear.  For example, $$\Re(\lambda z)=\Re((a+bi)(x+iy))=ax-by=\Re(\lambda)\Re(z)-\Im(\lambda)\Im(z)$$